# Removing whitespace before an XML before loading it

Tags: php, xml, feed, rss-reader

I built a small webpage that retrieves all kinds of news through XML feeds most websites offer. With `simplexml_load_file($url);` I simply load the feeds into my script.

One website however offers an invalid XML feed, because it starts with whitespace:

[image].

I found that this is a known Wordpress plugin related bug and I suspect it is the reason it is not working in my script. The W3C Feed Validation Service also replies "*Sorry. This feed does not validate. line 1, column 1: Blank line before XML declaration*".

As a user I would like to remove the whitespace myself (since the website owner is not responding). Is there a way to remove or change XML before feeding it into something like simplexml_load_file()?

I cannot use something like `ltrim()` because `file_get_contents()` returns false, so I have no way to modify the string in the first place.

Comment: This is not a duplicate! @bwoebi

I cannot use something like ltrim() because file_get_contents() returns false, so I have no way to modify the string in the first place.

Comment: So, then _that_ is your issue. Figure out why `file_get_contents()` fails. Perhaps it's a difference in headers like that you need `Accept: text/xml` or anything such.

Comment: If you fail to do so, please open a new question, which contains the headers sent (tcpdump, wireshark...) in both cases and let us help you on that specific issue.